# Como llamar función de mi componente en el render de un boton de un datatable despues del mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatables

Tengo un componente con la version 3 de vue, lo que estoy intentando hacer es llamar una funcion de mi componente desde el render de una columna del datatable, solo que no se si es posible.
Para este caso la funcion que intento mandar a llamar en el click de un boton es editCredential como se haria en el tempalte normalmente. Solo que esto actualmente no me funciona.
Lo que estoy tratando de evitar es definir un esuchador sobre la tabla y filtrar hasta que de con el boton ya que no me agrada tanto. Si alguien conoce alguna forma de hacer esto podria ayudarme.

```
export default{
    data() {
    return {
        credentials:[]
    }
    },
    methods: {
        getCredentials(){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url     : window.origin+"/apiadmin/credentialsincludes",
                data    : {opc:"credentials", action:"getCredentials"},
                method  : 'post',
                dataType:"json",
            }).then(resp=>{
                this.credentials = resp;
                this.generateTable();
            }).fail(resp=>{
                swal('Ocurrio un problema en la peticion en el servidor, favor de reportar a los administradores', {icon:'error'});
            }).catch(resp=>{swal('Ocurrio un problema en la peticion en el servidor, favor de reportar a los administradores', {icon:'error'});});
        },
        generateTable(){
            jQuery('#credenciales').DataTable( {
                dom: 'Blfrtip',
                data        : this.credentials,
                "autoWidth": true,
                "scrollCollapse": true,
                "searching": true,
                "paging": true,
                "language": {
                    "emptyTable":     "No se encontraron solicitudes registradas"
                },
                scrollX:"auto",
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'excel',
                        className: 'btn btn-default',
                        order: [[0, 'asc'], [5, 'asc']],
                    } 
                ],
                "columns": [
                    { width:"5%","data": "id_key" },
                    { width:"11%","data": "key" },
                    { width:"10%","data": "user_key" },
                    { width:"10%","data": "nombre_key" },
                    { width:"12%","data": "descripcion" },
                    { width:"12%","data": "nombre_unidad_negocio" },
                    { width:"10%","data": "nombre_cliente" },
                    { width:"10%","data": "nombre_producto" },
                    { width:"10%","data": "id_key",
                        render(data, type, data2, key, row) {
                            // console.log(data, type, data2, key, row);
                            return (1==1) ? `

                            <button type="button" @click="editCredential" class="btn animated pull-up btn-warning btn-sm editCredito" data-value=''><i class="la la-edit" style="font-size:11px;"></i></button>&nbsp;
                            <button type="button" class="btn animated pull-up btn-warning btn-sm editCreditoD" data-key='' data-value=''><i class="la la-trash-alt" style="font-size:11px;"></i></button>` : '';
                        },
                    },
                ],
    
            } );
        },
        editCredential(){
            console.log("hola");
        }
    },
    created() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.getCredentials();
        }, 500);
    },
    components:{

    },
    template:/* html */`
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 mb-2">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-success text-white btn-sm"> 
                        Agregar Credenciales <i class="la la-plus"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 mb-1">
                    <table class="table table-sm table-striped" style="width:100%;font-size:10px;" id="credenciales">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="credentials-th">ID</th>
                                <th class="credentials-th">KEY</th>
                                <th class="credentials-th">USER</th>
                                <th class="credentials-th">NOMBRE</th>
                                <th class="credentials-th">DESCRIPCION</th>
                                <th class="credentials-th">UNIDAD DE NEGOCIO</th>
                                <th class="credentials-th">CLIENTE</th>
                                <th class="credentials-th">PRODUCTO</th>
                                <th class="credentials-th">ACCIONES</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    `
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso, la directiva @click no puede ser utilizada porque no forma parte del template del component. Puedes escuchar eventos como este, si defines el boton dentro del template, y lo iteras dentro del tbody, solo que tendrias que hacer manualmente el rerender del datatable.

Puedieras utilizar otra libreria como [PrimeVue](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/datatable), que se encarga de todo el renderizado de la tabla, y tambien es flexible para la funcionalidad que necesitas.

Comment: Gracias fluid undefined, entiendo, gracias por la recomendacion!!!! ese PrimeVue viene empaquetado en alguna cdn????

Comment: Asi es estimado, que seria de este mundo si el empaquetamiento no existiera!!!!!!!! Te comparto la URL: https://github.com/primefaces/primevue (Seccion CDN). Si la respuesta de ayudo, echame la mando marcandola como aceptada.